# passenger window switch unidirectional, driver's switch bidirectional. diagnosis & treatment?

Tags: subaru, power-windows, impreza

2004 Subaru Impreza Outback Sport

My front passenger-side window switch will only roll the window down, but the driver's switch can roll it both up and down. There's only one motor, right? so there must be a problem with the switch. I'm pretty handy, but am a newbie to auto mechanics, so I'm reluctant to just start opening up the panel. Does this problem allow for a complete diagnosis, or will I need to do more testing? If the diagnosis is clear, what steps need to be taken to treat this? Will I need a new switch?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: feel free to answer, but by plugging in a switch from the rear i learned it's a faulty switch. $10 replacement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already fixed it, but I'll provide an answer for posterity...

The most likely causes of this are a faulty switch or faulty wiring. The switch can be easily tested by swapping it out for another (e.g. one of the back ones).

Wiring in car doors is notorious for failing, as the wires all have to go from the door through the 'snake' to the car body, and can fail through either fatigue from the constant flexing, or from wear if they are allowed to rub against the metalwork at either end - this is common where people have made aftermarket changes to the audio system and have disturbed the snake to add more wires. If replacing the switch doesn't fix it, identifying the appropriate wire and bypassing it often can...